# While converting character variable into integer, there is a message saying : NAs introduced by coercion. How to avoid this error?

Tags: r, dplyr, type-conversion, integer, na

I have tried to convert the character variable into integer variable using `as.integer` function. However, when the code is executed, the output returns the values as `NA`. The code is as follows,

```
library(tidyverse)
coal_data <- read.csv("http://594442.youcanlearnit.net/coal.csv", skip = 2)
coal_data %>% glimpse()
colnames(coal_data)[1] <- "region"
coal_long <- gather(coal_data, 'year', 'coal_consumption', -region)
coal_long %>% glimpse()
coal_long %>% separate(year, into = c("x", "year"), sep = "X")%>%
    select(-x)%>% glimpse()
class(coal_long$year)
coal_long$year <- as.integer(coal_long$year)
```

The output was as follows

```
coal_long %>% glimpse()



 Rows: 6,960
    Columns: 3
    $ region           <fct> "North America", "Bermuda", "Canada", "Greenland", "Mexico",...
    $ year             <int> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
    $ coal_consumption <chr> "16.45179", "0", "0.96156", "0.00005", "0.10239", "0", "15.3...
```

Actual output expected is getting the year in integer form. 
Many thanks in advance for looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the letters from `coal_long$year` before you convert to an integer. Try something like this.

```
coal_long$year # X1980 X1981 X1982 X1983, etc.
as.integer(str_remove(coal_long$year, "X"))
```

Here's a more generic approach that extracts all digits from the string before converting.

```
as.integer(str_extract(coal_long$year, "\\d+"))
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the code. The code provided by you helped in getting the year. However the class of the coal_long$year variable is still character. It did not get changed into integer.

Comment: Did you reassign coal_long$year? When I do `class(as.integer(str_remove(coal_long$year, "X")))` I get integer

Comment: Yes Sir, it worked after assigning coal_long$year. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

May as well make coal_consumption a double while you're at it...

```r
library(tidyverse)

coal_data <- read.csv("http://594442.youcanlearnit.net/coal.csv", skip = 2, na.strings = "--")

colnames(coal_data)[1] <- "region"
coal_long <- gather(coal_data, 'year', 'coal_consumption', -region)
coal_long %>% glimpse()
#> Rows: 6,960
#> Columns: 3
#> $ region           <chr> "North America", "Bermuda", "Canada", "Greenland", "…
#> $ year             <chr> "X1980", "X1980", "X1980", "X1980", "X1980", "X1980"…
#> $ coal_consumption <dbl> 16.45179, 0.00000, 0.96156, 0.00005, 0.10239, 0.0000…
coal_long <- coal_long %>% separate(year, into = c("x", "year"), sep = "X") %>%
  select(-x) %>% glimpse()
#> Rows: 6,960
#> Columns: 3
#> $ region           <chr> "North America", "Bermuda", "Canada", "Greenland", "…
#> $ year             <chr> "1980", "1980", "1980", "1980", "1980", "1980", "198…
#> $ coal_consumption <dbl> 16.45179, 0.00000, 0.96156, 0.00005, 0.10239, 0.0000…
class(coal_long$year)
#> [1] "character"
coal_long$year <- as.integer(str_remove(coal_long$year, "X"))
glimpse(coal_long)
#> Rows: 6,960
#> Columns: 3
#> $ region           <chr> "North America", "Bermuda", "Canada", "Greenland", "…
#> $ year             <int> 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980…
#> $ coal_consumption <dbl> 16.45179, 0.00000, 0.96156, 0.00005, 0.10239, 0.0000…
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing the code. It worked.

Comment: No problem glad to help

Answer (score 2):

You need to re-assign the `coal_long` after removing the `X` in the `year` column.

```
coal_long <- coal_long %>% 
  separate(year, into = c("x", "year"), sep = "X") %>% 
  select(-x) %>% 
  glimpse()

coal_long$year <- as.integer(coal_long$year)

coal_long %>% glimpse()

Rows: 6,960
Columns: 3
$ region           <fct> "North America", "Bermuda", "Canada", "Greenland", "Mexico", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "United States", "Cent…
$ year             <int> 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980…
$ coal_consumption <chr> "16.45179", "0", "0.96156", "0.00005", "0.10239", "0", "15.38779", "0.42011", "0", "0", "0.03476", "--", "0", "0…
```